# how to wait for a result in rxjs for a lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, rxjs

I am trying to write an async lambda function which is calling a function for sign up a user in cognito.
my problem is that in my lambda function, it is not waiting for the result and finish the execution. would you mind check what is my issue? I am new to rxjs. please help me.

mylambda function

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
         //poolData and params will fetch from event
         let source = await signup(poolData, params);
        console.log(source);
      });
```

my signup function

```
function signup(poolData, body) {
  const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

  const { username, password, attributes } = body;

  const attributesList = [];

  if (Array.isArray(attributes)) {
    attributesList.push(
      ...attributes.map(item => new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(item))
    );
  }

  let source =  Observable.create(observer  => {
    let output = (err, res) => {
      if (err) 
      { 
        observer.error(err);
      }
      else 
      {
        const cognitoUser = res.user;
        const data = {
          username: cognitoUser.getUsername(),
        };
        observer.next(data);
      }
      observer.complete();
    }
    userPool.signUp(username, password, attributesList, null, output);
  });

  let respond;

  let subscriber = {
    next(value) {
      console.log('Subscriber - next: ', value);
      respond = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': JSON.stringify({
          "username": value.username,
        })
      }
    }, error(err) {
      console.log('Subscriber - err: ', err);
      respond = err;
    },
    complete() {
      console.log('Subscriber - complete');
      return response;
    }
  };

  source.subscribe(subscriber);
}

module.exports = signup;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is totally normal.

So first thing first, an observable is not a promise which means you are not able to await a response with the `await` keyword, also I don't see anything to be returned from the `signup` function, which will probably lead to `undefined` to be logged anyways.

So how to fix that, one way to fix this issue is to use `toPromise()` which will turn your observable into a promise which then can be awaited wherever needed.

The other way (which is the rxjs way) will be to return from the `signup` function the observable and inside your `handler` function to subscribe for the response.

```js
let subscriber = {
    next(value) {
      console.log('Subscriber - next: ', value);
      respond = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': JSON.stringify({
          "username": value.username,
        })
      }
    }, error(err) {
      console.log('Subscriber - err: ', err);
      respond = err;
    },
    complete() {
      console.log('Subscriber - complete');
      return response;
    }
  };

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
         //poolData and params will fetch from event
        signup(poolData, params).subscribe(subscriber);
      })
```

Comment: So in this case, is it recommended to use rxjs for such scenario? I was thinking to try using rxjs instead of a promise for practice but based on what u said I need to use promise again on top of loading rxjs. Also, I wrote my code initially in the same way you wrote but I feel it is messy. is there any way to put subscribe function inside the signup and wait for result?

Comment: There is no way to put the subscribe inside the `singup`, wait for it to be resolved, and receiving a notification outside the function. The power of rxjs shines in the cases where you need to compose multiple async actions (you can also achieve the same result with promises but there are some downsides in some cases). So my advice especially for writing rest API is "If you don't have a problem that will be resolved by the (not just rxjs) library, don't use the library" and if the endgame plan is just to make an app for practice then keep on going with rxjs, it might seem messy at the start ..

Comment: But at some point when you create few factory functions to handle the common cases and reduce the boilerplate it will stary to look beautiful and simple.